# Compilation error incompatible types: java.sql.Connection cannot be converted to Connection

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jdbc

we have a project in school, and I want to use SQLite.

I did an tutorial on internet which use NetBeans to connect me on my DB and it work but my teacher probably don't have NB so I try to compile it on javac.
so this appears when i test it.

```
 Connection.java:72: error: incompatible types: java.sql.Connection cannot be converted to Connection
                                conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
                                                                  ^
Connection.java:78: error: cannot find symbol
                        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                                             ^
  symbol:   method createStatement()
  location: variable conn of type Connection
2 errors
```

so my code is here

```
        try {
            Connection conn = null;
            try {
                Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:c:\sqlite\test.db");
            } catch ( Exception e ) {
                System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
                System.exit(0);
            }
            System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            // create a new table

            stmt.execute(sqldoc);
            stmt.execute(sqlaud);
            stmt.execute(sqlvid);
            stmt.execute(sqlliv);
            stmt.execute(sqlcli);
            stmt.execute(sqlemp);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

in an other file, I had one more error, which concern getMetaData()

I hadn't take a look to this on internet but I don't find the answer to this error

Comment: Wrong import, ensure you have got import java.sql.Connection correctly

Comment: Use `import java.sql.Connection` at the top of your Java file.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but Netbeans can manage maven type projects, and I think that every Java IDE under the sun supports maven projects, so your teacher's IDE will most probably also support it.

Answer (score 2):

Given the error location (`Connection.java:72`) you are creating a class `Connection`, which conflicts with `java.sql.Connection`.

You either need to change your code to explicitly reference `java.sql.Connection`:

```
java.sql.Connection conn = null;
try {
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:c:\sqlite\test.db");
    // ...etc
```

Or you need to rename your own class `Connection` to something else, so it doesn't conflict with `java.sql.Connection` if you add an import for that class.

The second compilation error is just a follow up error with the same cause, as `conn` is defined as your own `Connection` class, which does not have a `createStatement()` method.